# Sharing primitive data among methods?

Tags: java

Say we have a public method "method," which uses private "subMethod1" and private "subMethod2" in its calculation.  These subMethods serve no other purpose than to break down "method" into more readable, encapsulated sub-parts, and to avoid code duplication within method.

We need each of these sub methods to operate on 2 or more primitive data types, which are local variables defined at the top of method.  We cannot pass them into the sub methods by reference, since java does not allow primitives to be passed by reference.

So our solution is to refactor, and change the local variables defined at the top of method to member variables, which can of course be read and written by both method and its sub-methods.  The problem is that now we have member variables that don't really exist to store object state, but only exist, effectively, during the execution of method.  Of course, in actuality they exist throughout the whole lifetime of the object, but they are only ever used during the execution of method, and they could vanish at other times without affecting the behavior of the object at all (keep in mind that method initializes the members to default values at the beginning of its method body).

Well, you say, just wrap the primitives in objects, keep them local within method, then have "method" pass those objects to its submethods, where they will be able to change its value since it was passed by reference as all objects are.  The problem is that "method" is used inside a simulation loop, where it will be run millions of times.  The object wrappers slow things down noticeably, and performance is key here.

So my question is: Is there any solution that will give me the same performance as my ugly "use members to share primitive data between methods" solution, but will also have good OO design?  Would an inner class wrapping the method, sub-methods, and primitive data be appropriate?

Thanks, 
Jonah

EDIT: Here is a cooked up code sample whose sole purpose is demonstrate the slowdown caused by using object wrappers, as described above:

```
public class TestSharedMembers {

protected int m17Multiples;
protected int m23Multiples;

public int methodPrimitive(int i) {

    m17Multiples = 0;
    m23Multiples = 0;

    calc17Primitive(i);
    calc23Primitive(i);

    return m17Multiples + m23Multiples;
}

private void calc17Primitive(int i) {
    if (i % 17 == 0) 
        m17Multiples++;
}
private void calc23Primitive(int i) {
    if (i % 23 == 0) 
        m23Multiples++;
}



/// using object wrappers
class IntWrapper {
    private int mInt;
    public IntWrapper(int i) {
        mInt = i;
    }
    public int getInt() {
        return mInt;
    }
    public void increment() {
        mInt++;
    }
}
public int methodObject(int i) {

    IntWrapper o17 = new IntWrapper(0);
    IntWrapper o23 = new IntWrapper(0);

    calc17Object(i, o17);
    calc23Object(i, o23);

    return o17.getInt() + o23.getInt();
}

private void calc17Object(int i, IntWrapper o) {
    if (i % 17 == 0) 
        o.increment();
}
private void calc23Object(int i, IntWrapper o) {
    if (i % 23 == 0) 
        o.increment();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestSharedMembers t = new TestSharedMembers();
    final int NUM_ITERS = 20000000;

    double start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int total = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<NUM_ITERS; i++) {
        total += t.methodPrimitive(i);
    }
    double stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(total);
    System.out.println(stop - start);

    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    total = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<NUM_ITERS; i++) {
        total += t.methodObject(i);
    }
    stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(total);
    System.out.println(stop - start);

}
}
```

EDIT 2: Another example to test Jon's theory.

```
public class TestSharedMembers {

protected int m17Multiples;
protected int m23Multiples;

public int methodPrimitive(int i) {

    m17Multiples = 0;
    m23Multiples = 0;

    calc17Primitive(i);
    calc23Primitive(i);

    return m17Multiples + m23Multiples;
}

private void calc17Primitive(int i) {
    if (i % 17 == 0) 
        m17Multiples++;
    if (i % 19 == 0) 
        m17Multiples++;
    if (i % 5 == 0) 
        m17Multiples++;
    if (i % 43 == 0) 
        m17Multiples++;
    if (i % 41 == 0) 
        m17Multiples++;
    if (i % 91 == 0) 
        m17Multiples++;
}
private void calc23Primitive(int i) {
    if (i % 23 == 0) 
        m23Multiples++;
    if (i % 17 == 0) 
        m23Multiples++;
    if (i % 19 == 0) 
        m23Multiples++;
    if (i % 5 == 0) 
        m23Multiples++;
    if (i % 43 == 0) 
        m23Multiples++;
    if (i % 41 == 0) 
        m23Multiples++;
    if (i % 91 == 0) 
        m23Multiples++;
}



/// using object wrappers
class IntWrapper {
    private int mInt1;
    private int mInt2;
    public IntWrapper(int i1, int i2) {
        mInt1 = i1;
        mInt2 = i2;
    }
    public int getInt1() {
        return mInt1;
    }
    public int getInt2() {
        return mInt2;
    }
    public void increment1() {
        mInt1++;
    }
    public void increment2() {
        mInt2++;
    }
}
public int methodObject(int i) {

    IntWrapper o = new IntWrapper(0,0);

    calc17Object(i, o);
    calc23Object(i, o);

    return o.getInt1() + o.getInt2();
}

private void calc17Object(int i, IntWrapper o) {
    if (i % 17 == 0) 
        o.increment1();
    if (i % 19 == 0) 
        o.increment1();
    if (i % 5 == 0) 
        o.increment1();
    if (i % 43 == 0) 
        o.increment1();
    if (i % 41 == 0) 
        o.increment1();
    if (i % 91 == 0) 
        o.increment1();
}
private void calc23Object(int i, IntWrapper o) {
    if (i % 23 == 0) 
        o.increment2();
    if (i % 17 == 0) 
        o.increment1();
    if (i % 19 == 0) 
        o.increment1();
    if (i % 5 == 0) 
        o.increment1();
    if (i % 43 == 0) 
        o.increment1();
    if (i % 41 == 0) 
        o.increment1();
    if (i % 91 == 0) 
        o.increment1();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestSharedMembers t = new TestSharedMembers();
    final int NUM_ITERS = 20000000;

    double start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int total = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<NUM_ITERS; i++) {
        total += t.methodPrimitive(i);
    }
    double stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(total);
    System.out.println(stop - start);

    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    total = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<NUM_ITERS; i++) {
        total += t.methodObject(i);
    }
    stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(total);
    System.out.println(stop - start);

}
}
```

Comment: why would the wrapper object solution be slower than the member variable solution?

Comment: i think it's because of the creation and destruction of the objects.  i do know it IS slower, though, because i tested it.

Answer (score 2):

I would look at creating a nested type which encapsulates all these currently-local variables, yes. Whether you then move the submethods *into* that type, or just keep the methods where they are and pass around a reference to an instance of this state class to the helper methods is up to you. You may find it slightly simpler to unit test the submethods if they're declared within the state class, but obviously the two solutions are really equivalent.

Do the submethods also need to access state in the existing class? If so, I'd probably keep the submethods in the existing class - I suspect that will keep the code clearer. I'm not a fan of true "inner" classes (with an implicit reference to the outer class) - I generally make my nested classes static, and do everything explicitly.

(Note that "objects are passed by reference" is a mis-statement of what happens in Java. The reality is that references are passed by value, which is subtly different. Java doesn't have any pass-by-reference semantics.)

Comment: Jon, thanks for your reply.  If I decided to keep the methods where they are and pass around an instance of the state class, then I assume that the instance in question would have to be a member variable of my existing (parent) class.  But then from a design perspective, don't we still have a member which exists not to store object state, but only to help implement methods?

Comment: @Jonah: Why would you need to have it as an instance variable? Create it as a local variable in `method()` and then pass the reference as an argument to `submethod1()`, `submethod2()` etc.

Comment: @Jon: Isn't that exactly what Jonah stated in his OP was slowing down his simulation?

Comment: @Jonah: Really? I thought you were talking about creating a mutable wrapper type for *each* of your primitive local variables, and passing those wrappers around. I'm still surprised if that made a huge difference... Posting some sample code would be really helpful.

Comment: @Jon: You're right, that's how it reads in the question, only when I first read it I mistook it for being one object wrapping all values, because that makes a lot more sense to me. So I thought that's what slowed down the app.

Comment: Jon, yes.  I cooked up a really silly example to illustrate my point.  Its has no purpose other than to illustrate the slowdown cause by an object wrapper.  The wrapper method adds about 50% more execution time.  I don's see a way to post code in comments, so I threw it up here: http://pastebin.ca/1931813

Comment: @Jonah: Your sample will add a lot of time because it's doing very little work for each method call... so you're creating *lots* of these objects. Changing the benchmarking code to perform 100 iterations within calc23Object (etc) made the difference *much* smaller. If you've got enough code that it's worth splitting it up, I would expect the difference to be mostly insignificant.

Comment: @Jon: 2 things.  In my actual code, the submethods perform their own iteration (a small loop of length 10) and some simple arithmetic.  I decided to split them up to improve readability and to avoid code duplication -- not really because they were doing a ton of calculation.

To me, from a learning perspective, the more important question is the theoretical one raised.  I think it would be possible to cook up a less silly example than mine that still retained the essential problem being illustrated.  Or do you think that's not true?  I'll think about it more and try to come up with something.

Comment: @Jonah: They don't have to be doing a "ton" of calculation - but more than one operation would help. Note that using my idea of a single class encapsulating both integers would help (rather than using two wrappers per call) as you'd be creating fewer objects. Also making it a static nested class helps. In my experience it's rarely worth micro-optimising this sort of thing - go for simple, readable code to start with and optimize *where you've got a proven bottleneck*.

Comment: @Jon: To test your theory, I combined to the 2 object wrappers into 1, and added some more code to the 2 sub-methods.  The object wrapped method is still taking about twice as long.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @Jonah: That sounds odd to me. When I made the submethods take longer, it made the difference almost negligible. Did you make the wrapper a static nested class too?

Comment: @Jon: Hey Jon.  I added the new test in a 2nd edit of the OP.  I should also mention that I did the change in 2 steps as I actually coded -- the first step was combining the 2 primitives into a single object wrapper.  Quite oddly, that step alone made the object method take much longer, about 6 times as long.  Then I made the submethods a bit less trivial, and it dropped down to about 2x as long.  The wrapper above isn't static, however if you make it static the execution time doesn't change much.

Comment: @Jonah: With your edited version, on my box `methodObject` runs faster than `methodPrimitive`. Having increased NUM_ITERS to 2000000000, I get results of 31195.0 (methodPrimitive) and 28021.0 (methodObject). You're not running in a debugger, are you?

Comment: @Jon: Curious and curiouser.  No, I am running as java application (F1) in eclipse 3.5.2.  My laptop is like 4 years old, but I don't think that should make a difference other than making both of them a bit slower..... My output gives 5031 for primitive, 8719 for object.

Comment: @Jonah: What version of Java are you using? I'm using Java 1.7, which may be relevant. Bear in mind that memory speed may have a significant bearing - the memory on my laptop is DDR3; if you have a reasonalbe processor but slow memory, that may explain it a bit.

Comment: I downloaded 1.7 and tried running it with that, but it made no difference.  My RAM is DDR2, I have 4GB but am on XP so it's like 3 effective.  Can you discuss how the RAM differences would explain the differences we're seeing?

Comment: @Jon: Also, above you said "2000000000" iterations, which is 100x more iterations than in the code I'm running.  But your execution time is only about 6x longer.  How can that be?  Are you just running a beast of a machine?  Finally, here is a shorter execution online which seems to agree with my results: http://ideone.com/2Pz07

Comment: @Jonah: My machine is a bit of a beast for a laptop - quad core i7 - but yes, it does seem odd. I'm just running it directly from the command line. Ah... I have a thought... maybe my machine is running the server JIT instead of the client JIT... that can make a big difference. Admittedly *that* scale of difference is still suspect, but it could be that there happens to be something in there which is just much more appropriate for this code.

Comment: Hmm... just run with `java -client` and it's a *bit* slower, but not enough to explain it. Just to be clear, other than changing NUM_ITERS, I'm using *exactly* your second bit of code. No changes at all.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than wrapping individual primitives or adding the primitives as fields in the class the method is in, could you instead make this method itself an object with primitive fields?

If the class where you currently have `method()` defined is `Foo`, rather than adding the primitives it uses to `Foo` make another class (an inner class, perhaps) `FooMethod` and, where you would have called `method()` before, do `new FooMethod().method()` instead. The primitive fields in `FooMethod` will then effectively be local variables since the `FooMethod` object is free to be GCed once the method call is finished.

Comment: I believe that's exactly what he's suggesting in the final paragraph: "Would an inner class wrapping the method, sub-methods, and primitive data be appropriate?"

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ShareLocal {

private final static class methods
{

    private int sharedInt;
    public void method(int init)
    {
    sharedInt=init; 
    ... 
    }
    private void meth1()
    {
    ... 
    }
    private void meth2()
    {
    ... 
    }
}
private ShareLocal.methods methodCall=new ShareLocal.methods();
void simulationLoop()
{
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)   
  methodCall.method(i);
}


}
```

I think the inner class as you mentioned is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

If you really regard a performance loss due to a wrapper object as a concern, then I would recommend not to extract the said 2 submethods. Large methods are bad smell, but if you need it for a simulation then "beautiful" object-oriented design might be 2nd priority.

Anyway, *don't* save intermediary state in member variables. First, because what you've already mentioned, second, because it also slows down your code, and third, because if you ever plan to have multiple threads execute the methods, you're lost with race conditions.

Comment: chiccodoro, a single long method would certainly answer my performance problems, but I don't think breaking down the methods creates any significant performance hit, as long as we aren't creating wrapper objects.  I havn't tested that statement, but I think it's true.  The larger issue is: somehow it seems wrong that designing correctly excludes good performance.  That either means that I havn't found the right solution yet, or that Java is limited in this respect.  In any case, the problem is forcing me to design with implementation in mind, which is not a good thing....

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could explain again why it is so important to you to have the fields vanish? If performance is as important as you say, why add this as a "requirement"?  It appears you already have a solution which avoids the cost of object creation.

If you want a more optimial solution, use arguments and return values.

```
public class TestSharedMembers { 
  public int methodPrimitive(int i) { 
    return calc17Primitive(i) + calc23Primitive(i); 
  } 
  private int calc17Primitive(int i) { 
    return i % 17 == 0 ? 1 : 0;
  } 
  private void calc23Primitive(int i) { 
    return i % 23 == 0? 1 : 0;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Peter, recall my example was a simplified version of the real problem, which would have been too long and cumbersome to paste in.  Your solution would indeed be exactly what I'd do if each sub-method only had to return 1 value.  The problem is that in the actual problem each submethod would need to return at least 2 values, and then we'd need to be returning objects or arrays, and we're back in the same boat.

Comment: Then you need to make use of fields. Perhaps you could give more explaination as to what your concern with this is?

Comment: BTW, a long can hold two int values, but it an ugly solution which is unlikely to help you in all cases.

Comment: Peter, my concern with using fields (which seems valid, based on the other replies) is that I am basically "hacking" the intended OO use of fields, which is to store object state.  In this case, the fields would not be storing object state, but acting as temporary placeholders to pass information between a method and its submethod during the execution of that method.